# Spring Boot PostgreSQL slow startup on local with database in server

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am new to Spring or Spring Boot and I have a **Java Spring Boot** application with **PostgreSQL database**.

While running **on local machine**, if I point to **local database** in application.yml, it takes about 20 seconds to start up. But if I point it to **database in QA server** it takes more than 5 mins to start up.

What is the reason behind this ? How to overcome this ?

I've done some reading and found out that this might be due to loading time for metadata, and I can use below line in application.yml to solve this.

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
```

Is this correct ? If it is, what exactly happens when we add the above lines to application.yml. And will this cause any issue's or side effects ?

Comment: I think problem with your network connection.. Check your Internet or Intranet connection..  You need a seemless connection with your QA Database such that hibernate interact accordingly.. Thanks

Comment: No the network connection is fine actually.

Comment: there is no such thing except the network connection in my openion...

Comment: @VikrantKashyap It does make sense that it is likely network issue cos If I login to QA server and run application there also it is fast. But the network is fine. Is there anyway to pinpoint this ?

Comment: I would turn on database logging of all statements and see what exactly the application does. Perhaps that way you can figure out if any of that activity is unnecessary and reduce it.